Can't get second bend to work
I have sheet metal object that I've set up with a rig that has 2 bends. Each bend in the rig has 5 little bones for a nicely curved bend which will bend to a total of 90 degrees to form a right angle bend. The rig bends perfectly to make two 90 degree bends, but when the sheet metal object is parented to the rig, only the first bend goes to 90 degrees. The second bend has the same setup, but only bends that portion of the object to 45 degrees, even though the bones are visibly bending to 90 degrees. The vertices are all matched up with the little bones in both bend areas, so I'm not sure what's causing the second set of vertices to not align with bones. Thanks for any help on this.
Blender file
Bending video samples





Can you possibly share your Blender project file? Or possibly post a few screenshots explaining your problem? It's kind of hard to wrap your head around the issue with only text like this. Instructions for sharing.

Hi @Jakemoyo, I added a the .blend file and some vids and screenshots for reference. Thanks for any help on this.

The Vertices of the left bend 012 flap should all be assigned to a single vertex group (left bend 012) with a full weight of 1.00. Instead, if any one of the flap's vertices are selected we will see that the vertex has been assigned to multiple vertex groups all which have a vertex weight of 1.00.

To compare, when we select a vertex of the left bend 006 flap we see it will only be assigned to a single vertex group, left bend 006.

To fix this, first we make sure that all the flap's vertices are assigned vertex group left bend 012 with a vertex weight of 1.00.
In Edit mode select all the vertices that make up the left bend flap, open the Object data Properties tab, and then with the left bend 012 vertex group selected hit the Assign button.

Next we need to remove all the unnecessary vertex groups from all the vertices of the left bend 012 flap.
We do this by selecting a vertex group from the list of vertex groups and hit the Remove button. The example below shows removing left bend 006 vertex group from all the selected vertices :

Repeat above for the other unnecessary vertex groups.

Now when we select any of the vertices that make up the left bend 012 flap they should only have the one left bend 012 vertex group assigned to it with a vertex weight of 1.00.

The left bend 012 flap should now bend to its full 90°:

